# How to test Thunk actions with Jest and Sinon

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I'm creating a simple action to fetch some data from an API with Thunk. It looks like this:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

function json(response) {
  return response.json();
}

/**
 * Fetches books from the server
 */
export function getBooks() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    fetch("http://localhost:1357/book", {mode: "cors"})
    .then(json)
    .then(function(data) {
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_BOOKS",
        devices: data
      });
    });
  }
};
```

It should call `fetch` once. I have verified that it does this, because it successfully pulls data when called in a web browser. However, when I write this test:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
let spy = sinon.spy(fetch);
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {getBooks} from '../../actions/getBooks';
import sinon from 'sinon';

const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('async actions', () => {

  it('calls the server', () => {
    const store = mockStore({books: []});
    store.dispatch(getBooks());
      expect(spy.callCount).toEqual(1);
      spy.restore();
  });
});
```

However, this test fails, and the `spy`'s call count is 0. I suspect this is due to fetch being imported by the action before the test, which is why the spy is created at the top of the file. However, this does not work. What is the recommended way to test that `fetch` is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from http://arnaudbenard.com/redux-mock-store/, part Asynchronous action.

I'm guessing it happens because you are not using a promise in your test.

```
it('calls the server', (done) => {
    const store = mockStore({books: []});
    store.dispatch(getBooks()).then(() => {
      expect(spy.callCount).toEqual(1);
      spy.restore();
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I run the test, I get an error saying `cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. I'm assuming this means the store is not defined, but we did define it. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Nevermind - I had to change to code to say `return fetch(localhost...` instead of just `fetch(localhost...`.